# Can anybody explain me like i'm 5 how the variables work on a function?

Tags: c++, function, int, parentheses

So for the past 4 months i've been learning C++ and I made lots of progress, actually getting very close to learning graphs soon.
There's just one thing that I still have problems and and I just don't get it, and that is the variables on a function.

Basically I do not know what kind of variables to put inside the () of a function in the beginning, and what variables I need to put after.

I know it depends on the exercise, so i'll try to give an example.

so I want to calculate the sum of a and b in a function.

```
int calculateSum(int a, int b){
    int sum;
}
```

so why do I put under the function and not inside the parenthesis?
why can't it just be like:

```
int calculateSum(int a, int b, int sum){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Why do you not try to implement it both ways and tells us how it went?

Comment: well.. that's just an example, maybe here it would work but on others it doesn't...and that doesn't really answer my question, or maybe im just dumb

Comment: The second way won't work in this particular example :)

Comment: Okay, but why???

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but a text book would be best before asking a question here.

Comment: I know, I also watched youtube videos with explanations regarding about this problem that i'm finding, but I thought somebody here could've explained it to me like im 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables inside the `()` are the *parameters* of your function. That is, the inputs it expects when it is called from other code. The variables inside the `{}` are for use exclusively *inside* your function.

Your first example makes sense - you'd use it something like this:

```
int answer = calculateSum(1, 2);
```

What would you pass as an argument for the `sum` parameter in your second example? It's sort of a meaningless request - the caller of your function wants to get the sum *back* from your routine.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay i'm actually starting to get it after I read what you said for like 5 times. So basically what you're saying is that in the parenthesis I just use the "useless" variables that don't have to go into int main() and outside of that I use what I actually want to do with that function?

Comment: @jaketherazvy there are no "useless variables" in what you replied to. Also why is `main` relevant? You could be calling the function from anywhere. I get the impression that you don't actually understand this at all.

Comment: okay, interesting. I didn't know I can call a function into another function.. so that's good to know. I have only been learning for 4 months and the very basics on every lesson, something that is enough for me to solve exercises. I did not go in very depth with everything. I also called them "useless variables" because I did not have any better synonyms to what I meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

In reality everything depends on the definition of the function. For example we can define a function as follows.
int CalculateSum (int a, int b, int sum);

This function necessarily receives three integers a, b and sum.
The body of the function can be defined
for example like this:

```
int CalculateSum (int a, int b, int sum) {
sum = a + b;
return sum;
}
```

We can also define the function as well.

int CalculateSum (int a, int b);
  This function receives two integers a and b.

the body of the function can be

```
int CalculateSum (int a, int b) {
int sum;
sum = a + b;
return sum;
}
```

If you are the creator of the function you can do it however you want, but if the function is already defined you will have to use it as the definition begins.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a function, you need to split your mind into two different personas. You have the developer who's writing the function, we'll call them FuncDev, and you have the developer who will be calling that function, we'll call them CallDev.

When FuncDev is writing the function, they need to think about what CallDev needs the function to do and in what situations they'll be calling it. What information does CallDev have when they're calling the function? What do they want the function to actually *do* or give back?

In the case of `calculateSum`, CallDev is going to have two numbers that they want to find the sum of. And FuncDev only needs two numbers to correctly calculate a sum. So everyone's in agreement here: to call `calculateSum`, you should provide two numbers and get a number back (that's the sum of those two).

All of this information can be found in the function header:

```
//- This function will return (or give back) an integer
//|                   - This function requires two integers to do its job
//v                   v
int calculateSum(int a, int b) {
```

You don't need to also include an `int sum` parameter because A. that's not something CallDev will have at the time of calling the function. The whole point they're calling is to get a sum in the first place! And B. that's not something FuncDev needs to calculate the sum. So you'd be imposing an extra condition on anyone calling the function without gaining anything in the function implementation.

Also, everything that happens inside the curly braces in the function logic itself, CallDev should never need to know about. Whether FuncDev decides to make a `int sum` variable to hold the sum before they return it, etc... shouldn't matter.

Usually, when I'm developing, I'll make the function calls before I even write the functions. So in your case, I may be going along and think "Hmm, I really need the sum of two numbers here. I have two numbers onhand, it'd be nice if I could just call `calculateSum(num1, num2)` and get the value I need." So I'll actually just write the call to the function and keep going<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. In actuality, this looks like writing tests when applicable for the function and *then* writing it. But the premise is the same. I'm defining the behavior, inputs and outputs of the function all before I write it.</sup>